# WPF Package Load Failure?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

Package Load Failure

Package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Xaml' has failed tot load properly. . . yadda, yadda, yadda.

So now what? This package is somewhat important since I was hoping to do some WPF stuff this afternoon. Tried running without it and my XAML design view is gone.

I already tried "devenv /resetsettings" from the command prompt.

Thanks,
Scott

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try repairing the install.

- Control Panel
- Add Remove Programs
- Select Visual Studio 2008 and choose "repair"

Did you recently install any updates to Visual Studio or any Add-Ins?  If so can you please list them?

Comment: Repair was successful. I did not install any add-ons or apply any updates to VS. A few weeks ago, I downloaded KaXaml and played around with that.

Answer (score 1):

Install SP1: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=FBEE1648-7106-44A7-9649-6D9F6D58056E&displaylang=en

I had this problem after a fresh install of VS2008 Team System. Tried loading the updates, running setup, re-installing. No luck.

Installed SP1 and bingo! No more package load failures.

Comment: Worked for me. I'm on Windows 7 but I didn't have to do that on Windows Server 2003.

Answer (score 0):

I -FINALLY- saw this error going into Tools|Options|Environment Fonts and Colors after trying everything I could think of to get it not to crash when I chose Tools|Import and Export Settings.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when I installed Visual Studio Professional.

My theory was that it was because I already had Visual C# 2008 Express Edition installed.

Once I uninstalled both then reinstalled Visual Studio Professional it worked.

This is consistent with the OP's solution, which was to uninstall anything else which implemented XAML functionality.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, just reinstalling SP1 didnt worked

Then i saw ive had two languages mixed in the IDE. So ive checked the installed programs and found:

- Microsoft Visual Studio Tools For Applications 2.0 ENU
- Microsoft Visual Studio Tools For Applications 2.0 Language Pack - ESN

When ive uninstalled the additional pack, the design views started to work again

Answer (score 0):

In my case the machine.config file had gotten some bad XML due to a recent installation.  There were two closing tags.  After we corrected the bad XML, .NET works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Abraham for the hint.  I was missing an end tag  in my .NET 2.0 x86 machine.config.

However I had already spent hours repairing, uninstalling, installing and installing service packs.

WOULDN'T IT BE NICE IF VISUAL STUDIO 2008 GAVE A "MACHINE.CONFIG" CORRUPT ERROR!